# Passing a template as content, which is in turn passed to another component

Tags: angular

Using Angular 4.0.3

I'm creating a component `my-component`, which has an input of `value`, and is passed an `ng-template` as content. Example usage would be:

```html
<my-component [value]="value">
  <ng-template let-value>
    <p><strong>Value rendered in user supplied template: {{value}}</strong></p>
  </ng-template>
</my-component>
```

It's the job of `my-component` to figure out whether the user is on a mobile device or not. If they are, we want to render a `my-native-component`. Otherwise, it'll render a `my-custom-component`.

My code for `my-component` so far is:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
  <my-custom-component *ngIf="useCustom" [value]="value">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateVariable"></ng-template>
  </my-custom-component>
  
  <my-native-component *ngIf="!useCustom" [value]="value">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateVariable"></ng-template>
  </my-native-component>
  `
})
class MyComponent {
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
  private templateVariable: TemplateRef;
  
  @Input()
  private value: string;
  
  @Input()
  private useCustom: bool = false;
}
```

To keep the example simple, there's no checking of whether the user is on mobile or not here. Instead, a `useCustom` input has been added.

The template passed as the content is referenced as `templateVariable`, and is passed as a new template via `ng-template` and `ngTemplateOutlet`.

In this example, `my-native-component` and `my-custom-component` are identical, except for their names. They have the same `value` input as `my-component`, and also receive a template as their content. This is what `my-native-component` looks like:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-native-component',
  template: `
  <h3>my-native-component (value: {{value}})</h3>
  <p>Rendered template:</p>
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateVariable" [ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: value}"></ng-template>
  <p>Done</p>
  `
})
class MyNativeComponent {
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
  private templateVariable: TemplateRef;
  
  @Input()
  private value: string;
}
```

I can't figure out why the passed template is never rendered when the app runs. Perhaps I have a misunderstaning on how `ng-template` works?

The full runnable code is available on Plunker - https://embed.plnkr.co/fiDECy5gamOLvjPo2uhN/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no `[ngOutletContext]`. It's `[ngTemplateOutletContext]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Idea is you need to pass the template down to the hierarchy tree.
See plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/hwww2QXDh9Je5Bc9ld3O?p=preview

In my-native-component:

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: {$implicit: value}"></ng-container>
```

In my-component:

```html
<my-native-component *ngIf="!useCustom" [value]="value" [template]="template">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateVariable"></ng-template>
</my-native-component>
```

In my-app:

```html
<my-component [value]="value" [useCustom]="false" [template]="test"><!-- toggle useCustom true/false -->
  <ng-template #test let-value>
    <p><strong>Value rendered in user supplied template: {{value}}</strong></p>
  </ng-template>
</my-component>
```

Put this in components to allow the transfer of template.

```js
@Input()
private template: TemplateRef;
```

Must keep this in mind. `<ng-template>` must need a container to output its content. It's hidden in HTML by default. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#template

Comment: Thanks, but that's defining a new template in `my-native-component`. Do you know how to make `my-native-component` render the template that was passed to `my-component`?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of passing a reference as an input. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When you added ngTemplateOutlet it become not a template, so the component won't see it as @ContentChild(TemplateRef).

```
 <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateVariable"></ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct but it uses a different approach as yours. The only thing that you need to change is the HTML template in your `MyNativeComponent`.

You should use one of these:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateVariable" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: value}"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateVariable; context: {$implicit: value}"></ng-container>
```

See [this link](http://www.bentedder.com/angular-4-templates-passing-methods-context-ngTemplateOutlet-ngTemplateOutletContext/) for more info